# NavigationController, keep logo on top without transsition

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I have a logo that appear on top of all my UIViewController(controlled by NavigationController).

When I get the transition between UIViewController, the logo also swipe.

What I want:  I want to logo(60 pixel height) to always stay. And the swipe transition to appear below the logo.

I've tried this in view delegate, but the logo also swipe :(

```
     let logo = UIImage(named: "logo.png") 
     let imageView =UIImageView(image:logo)
     self.navigationItem.titleView = imageView
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue: You have the logo swiping when transiting to next VC.

Desired Result: You want to have the logo show up on each VC without the swipe animation. But still have the Swipe animation running for everything below the logo.

What I would do is make a UIScrollView and keep the logo as just a UIImageView.

If you have github repo of this app I can take a look for you.

Answer (score 0):

Subclass the `UINavigationController` and in the `viewDidLoad`, configure the logo image view and add it to the `navigationBar` as a subview. Also, since we're adding it to the navigation bar which is only 44px in height, so a logo with a height of 60px would overflow the bounds.

```
class NavigationController: UINavigationController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        let logo = UIImage(named: "logo.png")!
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: logo)
        let width = logo.size.width * 60 / logo.size.height

        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        imageView.frame.size = CGSize(width: width, height: 60)
        imageView.center = navigationBar.convert(navigationBar.center, to: navigationBar)

        navigationBar.addSubview(imageView)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer.  This way, Y still see the logo "moving" from left to right(following the view transition).  I need to keep the view always on its position, event when going from one ViewController to Another

Comment: I have tested it and the image view does not move when pushing or popping a view controller.